# Select Items and display in same view. Return results to controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I am new to mvc and fairly young with Javascript so I apologize for the wrong/missing code. I am trying to make a view where the user has a drop down list and items selected via btnAdd will be dynamically displayed in the same view below the btnAdd button. I am assuming the best way to do this would be with JavaScript. After the user has made there choices they will click the btnckout button and there selections will be returned to the controller. Here is what I have so far. I am a little stuck so any help would be appreciated!

View:

```
@model OnlineTakeout.Models.ProductView

@{
     Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
     <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()){
<div>
    Pick Product:
    <br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.ProductId, Model.Products) 
    <br />
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="AddToOrder" id="btnAdd" />    
    </p>
</div>
    }
<div>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {    

    //Added Items would display here after individual btnAdd button presses  

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="CheckOut" id="btnChkOut" />    
   </p>

 }
</div>

</body>
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(addProduct);
    })

    $(function () {
        $("#btnChkOut").click(saveProducts);
    })

    var productList = [];
    var id = $("#ProductId").val();

    // This function would also display these items on view
    function addProduct() {
        productList.push(id);
    };


    function saveProducts() {
        $.post("/Product/Index/" + productList());
    }

    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Product/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ProductView();
        var products = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductId = 1, Name = "Product One", Price = 1.00m },  
            { new Product { ProductId = 2, Name = "Product Two", Price = 2.00m } }};
        model.Products = new SelectList(products, "ProductId", "Name");

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(int[] prodList)
    {

        return Json("Index");
    }
```

Comment: where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: The addProduct button adds items to the productlist but thats about it. I dont know how I would get this to display correctly on the view. Would I loop through productList and create a dom element for each item? Then I need to make sure I pass the productlist to the controller correctly. Not sure if I am doing the right or not. Views are really new to me. Not sure if that helps...

Comment: I think it should be like `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Product, Model.Products)`.. that Func<> delegate is the item to be selected by default among the list `Products`

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do this is by using jQuery.

You will need to create an event handler in jQuery for the change event of your drop down list that is supposed to trigger this change. When that fired, post to an action in your controller that is going to bind a partial controller and return the partial view. It is important to have a return type of ActionResult - that will return the HTML back to success method of your post. Then just embed the HTML on the page and you are done.